# For Which Values Of $t$ Is The Following An Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra

> For which values of $t$ is  $\langle{ p,q\rangle} = \int_{t}^{2}{p(x)q(x)dx}$ an inner product on $V = P_2$ ?

This question has me stumped. I know that to be an inner product, it must respect

1. Symmetry
2. Linearity
3. Positive Definite

but I don't know how to work with it.

Some hints would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

$\frac{a^2}{5}(2^5 - t^5) + \frac{1}{2}ab(2^4-t^4) + \frac{1}{3}(2ac + b^2)(2^3 -t^3) +bc(2^2 -t^2) +c^2(2-t) > 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Properties 1 and 2 will hold regardless of your choice of $t$.  On the other hand, positivity will hold if and only if for *any non-zero* $p \in P_2$, we have $\langle p,p \rangle > 0$.  For which $t$ will this be the case?

Comment: I updated the op, could you check it out? I feel I overcomplicated it.

Comment: Yes, you did.  Note that if $a < b$ and if $f$ is continuous with $f(x) \geq 0$ and $f$ is not the zero function, we always have
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx > 0
$$

Comment: Therefore this holds true $\forall t \in [-\infty, 2]$ ?

Comment: Almost. It doesn't hold for $t=2$.